# Probability distribution question (S2)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This question came up in my textbook:

"A town has five fire engines operating independently, each of which spends 94% of the time in its station on standby. Find the probability that at least 3 fire engines are available."

The answer at the back was: 99.8%

Could someone please explain the best method to use to answer this questions?
Much appreciated.

Comment: You could describe this using a [Binomial Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  $Pr(\text{at least three of five available}) = \sum\limits_{k=3}^5 \binom{5}{k}(0.94)^k(1-0.94)^{5-k}$

Comment: Thank you very much for this equation, I used it and reached the correct answer :)))) I was getting the wrong answer because I was using geometric distribution, however in this questions, the sequence of fire engines available is irrelavent

Answer (score 0):

Draw five distinct horizontal lines, each representing the state of a particular engine. On top of each line, write S for standby or N for not on standby. See how many different ways you can have 3 or more standby (e.g. SSSNN, SNSNS,...). Find the probability of a particular five letter configuration using independence. Multiply this probability by the number of configurations you've counted.

Answer (score 0):

Label the engines $(A, B, C, D, F)$. At least three available says that three, four or five are available. The probability of five is $0.94^5$; of four is the number of different sets of four available, ie 4 ($(A,B,C,D),(A,B,C,E),(A,B,D,E),(A,C,D,E)$), times the probability of each, which is $0.94^4 * (1-0.94)$ (as four must be available and one unavailable). I'll leave you to work out the exactly formula for the probability that three are available, but it's done like this: how many different ways can you pick three out of five; what is the probability of each (they'll all have the same probability as all independent with same standby-time); now multiply these together.

Now, to get the probability of *at least three*, you simply add up the probabilities for 3, 4 and 5.

---

Suppose instead that you have $N$ fire engines. Suppose they all act independently (as in your example). Suppose the probability that they have probability $p$ of being on standby. What is the probability that at least $n$ of them will be available ($1 \le n \le N$, of course!)?

Note that the case of your question is where $N = 5$, $p = 0.94$ and $n = 3$; what I've asked above is a (natural) generalisation.

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed explanation - I used binomial distribution equation, and did the sum of the probability of 3 fire engines which got me 0.998 :) Much appreciated !!!!!!!( i noticed it also works for 1 minus probability of 2 fire engines, which makes sense)

Comment: Yes, it certainly does. In fact, that's a good point, and it is actually easier to calculate that. I've added a bonus question to the end of my answer. Answer it if you want to, but of course you don't need to it you don't want to!